# Suppress the bash execution trace (set -x) from the outside of the script

Tags: bash, shell, set

I tried finding an answer to this question, but got no luck so far:

I have a script that runs some other scripts, and many of those other scripts have "set -x" in them, which makes them print every command they execute. I would like to get rid of that but retain the information if any of the scripts send the error message to stderr.

So I can't simply write  `./script 2>/dev/null`

Also, I don't have privileges to edit those other scripts, so I can't manually change the set option.

I was thinking about logging everything from stderr to the separate file and filtering out the tracing commands, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: `./script 2>some_file`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With `bash` 4.1 and above, you can do

```
BASH_XTRACEFD=7 ./script.bash 7> /dev/null
```

(also works when `bash` is invoked as `sh`).

Basically, we're telling `bash` to output the `xtrace` output on file descriptor 7 instead of the default of 2, and redirect that file descriptor to `/dev/null`. The fd number is arbitrary. Use a fd above 2 that is not otherwise used in your script. If the shell you're entering this command in is `bash` or `yash`, you can even use a number above 9 (though you may run into problems if the file descriptor is used internally by the shell).

If the shell you're calling that `bash` script from is `zsh`, you can also do:

```
(export BASH_XTRACEFD; ./script.bash {BASH_XTRACEFD}> /dev/null)
```

for the variable to be automatically assigned the first free fd above 9.

For older versions of `bash`, another option, if the `xtrace` is turned on with `set -x` (as opposed to `#! /bin/bash -x` or `set -o xtrace`) would be to redefine `set` as an exported function that does nothing when passed `-x` (though that would break the script if it (or any other `bash` script it invokes) used `set` to set the positional parameters).

Like:

```
set()
  case $1 in
    (-x) return 0;;
    (-[!-]|"") builtin set "$@";;
    (*) echo >&2 That was a bad idea, try something else; builtin set "$@";;
  esac

export -f set
./script.bash
```

Another option is to add a DEBUG trap in a `$BASH_ENV` file that does `set +x` before every command.

```
echo 'trap "{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null" DEBUG' > ~/.no-xtrace
BASH_ENV=~/.no-xtrace ./script.bash
```

That won't work when `set -x` is done in a sub-shell though.

As @ilkkachu said, provided you have write permission to any folder on the filesystem, you should at least be able to make a copy of the script and edit it.

If there's nowhere you can write a copy of the script, or if it's not convenient to make and edit a new copy every time there's an update to the original script, you may still be able to do:

```
 bash <(sed 's/set -x/set +x/g' ./script.bash)
```

That (and the copy approach) may not work properly if the script does anything fancy with `$0` or special variables like `$BASH_SOURCE` (such as looking for files that are relative to the location of the script itself), so you may need to do some more editing like replace `$0` with the path of the script...

Comment: Your first answer is exactly what  I needed, clean and elegant. Could you explain a little how does it work? Why the number 7? What could other numbers be used for? Thanks.

Comment: @human, see edit

Comment: The `{BASH_XTRACEFD}>` trick works in `bash` 4.1 or later as well.

Comment: @chepner, yes the feature was added to zsh, ksh93 and bash at the same time upon a suggestion by a zsh developer. But, here it doesn't work for `ksh93` or `bash` in that the variable is not passed in the environment of the command (compare `<shell> -c 'export fd; printenv fd {fd}> /dev/null'` in `zsh`, `bash` and `ksh93`). You could make it work in `ksh93`/`bash` by doing it in two steps or possibly using `eval`, but for `bash`, that would have side effects if the xtrace option was on.

Answer (score 5):

Since they're scripts, you *could* make copies of them, and edit those.

Other than that, filtering the output would seem simple, you could explicitly set `PS4` to something more unusual than a single plus, to make the filtering easier:

```
PS4="%%%%" bash script.sh 2>&1 | grep -ve '^%%%%'
```

(of course that will collapse stdout and stdin, but piping just stderr in Bash gets a bit hairy, so I'll ignore that)

Comment: Piping just stderr is easy: `PS4="%%%%" bash script.sh 2> >(grep -ve '^%%%%')`.

Comment: @Patrick, doing that in `bash` has issues as that `grep` is run asynchronously (bash is not waiting for it, so it can (and often does) output things after the next command in the script is started).